# Apache's SetEnvIf to another variable in .htaccess

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, setenv

Is it possible using SetEnvIf to set a variable to the content of another variable? and if so, how?

For example

```
SetEnvIf defined_htaccess_var ^(.*)$ has_been_defined=%{defined_htaccess_var}
```

So the idea is, if inside the apache.conf or httpd conf `defined_htaccess_var` has been defined, then `has_been_defined` inside the .htaccess should now contain the value of it?

Note. This is for apache 2.2

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is `SetEnvIf attribute regex [!]env-variable[=value]` 
source : https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_setenvif.html

for example:

```
store URI in has_been_defined
SetEnvIf Request_URI (.*) has_been_defined
```

After it depend of what you want to store

by the way `.*` in regexp mean all, so `^` (start with) & `$` (end with) is not needed

Comment: I want the store the variable thats defined in the example and question, need to check if a variable exists, and assign the value of that variable to another if it does.